# Spring , Camel, JMS Integration

Tags: spring, jms, apache-camel

Am 100% new to JMS and Camel

This is the Scenario

I have a Spring Web application, a JMS (ActiveMQ), Camel

The web application needs to send information to JSM, through camel in an asynchronous manner.
i.e. After sending information to Camel, the website should not wait for the response. The web page should continue.

And , my application should listen to the queue for any response in the Queue. Once , any response is received, a specific bean has to be invoked.

Is this possible???

This is the configuration in my client

**Camel Context :**

```
<!-- START SNIPPET: e1 -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
  <!-- END SNIPPET: e1 -->

  <!-- START SNIPPET: e2 -->
  <camel:camelContext id="camel-client">
    <camel:template id="camelTemplate"/>
  </camel:camelContext>
  <!-- END SNIPPET: e2 -->

  <!-- START SNIPPET: e3 -->
  <!-- Camel JMSProducer to be able to send messages to a remote Active MQ server -->
  <bean id="jms" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61610"/>
  </bean>
  <!-- END SNIPPET: e3 -->

</beans>
```

**Camel Code :**

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("camel-client.xml");

// get the camel template for Spring template style sending of messages (= producer)
ProducerTemplate camelTemplate = context.getBean("camelTemplate", ProducerTemplate.class);

System.out.println("Invoking the multiply with 22");
// as opposed to the CamelClientRemoting example we need to define the service URI in this java code
int response = (Integer)camelTemplate.sendBody("jms:queue:numbers", ExchangePattern.InOut, 22);
System.out.println("... the result is: " + response);
```

This is working good. But the prblem is , this is synchronous.

I want this to be asynchronous.

How to do it

Comment: In that case , how is it possible? Updating my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is a simple

```
int response = (Integer)camelTemplate.sendBody("jms:queue:numbers", ExchangePattern.InOut, 22);
```

This should be

```
int response = (Integer)camelTemplate.sendBody("jms:queue:numbers",22);
```

Just dont mention the `ExchangePattern` and you are done.

**Moral :** Please do read documentation properly .

Answer (score 0):

You won't need to do all that stuff in the Camel Remoting example (which I suspect you have started out with).

So, you want to stage some processing through a queue. Just so that I don't misinterpret this:

```
Web Request -> JMS queue -> Camel -> Bean -> Done
```

Create a route:

```
<camel:camelContext id="camel-client">
   <camel:template id="camelTemplate"/>
   <camel:route>
      <camel:from uri="jms:queue:myQueue"/>
      <camel:bean ref="someBean"/>
    </camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>
```

Then in your code, just fire of the message:
    camelTemplate.asyncSendBody("jms:queue:myQueue", ExchangePattern.InOnly, someData);

Comment: camelTemplate.asyncSendBody("jms:queue:myQueue", ExchangePattern.InOnly, someData);

This makes good sense, but when will I get back my data. Will the logic continue from where it left?

Comment: Well, say you do ExchangePattern.InOut instead, the asyncSendBody will return a `Future` object to grab your return data later on. However, you said the web page will continue to load (and I assumed, complete?). So, when do you want to read back the response?

Comment: This is the scenario, the page loads -> user operates -> send data to camel -> user contiues with the site -> camel/jms responds -> system updates something in the app/db -> user gets a pop up

Comment: sure. but camel/jms will only do parts of this, not the pop up stuff, since that sounds like web push technology.

Comment: yup!Pop up is the UI section